# sql oracle вложенный josn

Tags: sql, oracle

Имею следующее вложение в таблице

```
[{"choice":[{"type":"ab","id":3453,"b_id":8989,"shar":""}],"condition":"qwert"},{"choice":[{"type":"ab","id":5436,"b_id":7865,"shar":""}],"condition":"uyutor"}]
```

Просьба, подсказать, можно ли разбить строку на колонки в которой бы находился блок `choice`,
блоков choice соответственно может быть как 1 так и более 2,
Спасибо!

Comment: [JSON_TABLE()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973)

Comment: можете показать пример? 
буду признателен вам!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT test.id json_id, parsed_json.*
FROM test,
     JSON_TABLE(val, '$[*].choice' COLUMNS ( row_number FOR ORDINALITY,
                                             type VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.type',
                                             id INT PATH '$.id',
                                             b_id INT PATH '$.b_id',
                                             shar VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.shar'
                                           )
               ) AS parsed_json;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=167aea3df47315609f5fe4e2d0e90315)